# How Do You Create a Local Reference a TabItem?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabitem

Trying to parse Maplines for an airport.  Each airport can have X number of different configurations.  In code behind I parse each configuration into a separate collection of custom objects which is data bound to the `TabItem` below.  Currently this `TabItem` is "Hard Coded" in the XAML body.  How do I create a template that I can declare from Code behind so I can create X copies of the `TabItem`?

Thanks!

```
<TabItem x:Name="TabTerminalMaplineDefined" Header="Airways Defined">
    <Grid x:Name="GridTerminalMaplineDefined" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

        <!--AirwaysFixes Mapping Configuration ListView Start - Lists all the fixes that make up the airway-->
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewTerminalMaplineDefined" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="Auto" FontSize="9">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Click="SortClickAirwaysDefined" Tag="Name" Content="Name" />
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=X_Y_Beginning}" >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader   Content="Segment Start" />
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=X_Y_Ending}" >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader  Content="Segment End" />
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Category}" >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Click="SortClickAirwaysDefined" Tag="Category" Content="Category" />
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Comment: I agree this is the right answer, but do to my own limitations was unable to make it work.  The work around to me was to declare a tab item and put it below the tab control in a stack panel.  When the user clicks the tab then I bind the appropriate collection to the Tabitem.